# use angular variable inside angular factory

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

*I am new to angular...* in below code i need to use variable scope  `$scope.slugname` **inside Angular Factory(Test)**..

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);

myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope, Test) {
  $scope.slugname ="slugname";
  $scope.test = new Test();
});

myApp.factory('Test', function($http) {
  var test = function() {
    this.items = [];
    this.busy = false;
    this.after = '';
  };

  Test.prototype.nextPage = function() {
    if (this.busy) return;
    this.busy = true;

    var url = 'baseURL/?slug='+$scope.slugname;  //<-- I need to use variable($scope.slugname) here
    $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
      var items = data.data.children;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        this.items.push(items[i].data);
      }
      this.after =  this.items[this.items.length - 1].id;
      this.busy = false;
    }.bind(this));
  };

  return Test;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't use scope variables inside factory. alternatively you can pass the scope variable as parameter to the factory function.

```
myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope, Test) {
  $scope.slugname ="slugname";
  $scope.test = new Test($scope.slugname );
});

myApp.factory('Test', function($http) {
  var test = function() {
    this.items = [];
    this.busy = false;
    this.after = '';
  };

  Test.prototype.nextPage = function(name) {
    if (this.busy) return;
    this.busy = true;

    var url = 'baseURL/?slug='+$scope.slugname;
    $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
      var items = data.data.children;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        this.items.push(items[i].data);
      }
      this.after =  this.items[this.items.length - 1].id;
      this.busy = false;
    }.bind(this));
  };

  return Test;
});
```

Comment: `var url = 'baseURL/?slug='+$scope.slugname;` **instead**  `var url = 'baseURL/?slug='+name;` Right..?

Comment: yp. Just replace the scope variables inside the factory

Comment: sure. make sure to mark it as answer if this helped.